# Hibernate differente method name as field

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Is it possible that hibernate use a getter with a different name as the field?

```
....
private ComplexObject test;

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)   
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "number_format")
public ComplexObject getSomeStuff() {
    ....
    return test;
}
....
```

I always get an Exception

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   ... 21 common frames
>   omitted
>
> **Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ComplexObject, at table: table, for columns:**
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(extension_form_element_number_format)]
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  ... 29
>   common frames omitted

if the mehtod is not named by the field (in this case getTest()).

thanks

Comment: If you use the Property Access Strategy instead of Field Access Strategy it should be no problem. But you would probably have to change your existing entities if they were all written for Field access until now.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS i already added the @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) strategy to my method, i just forgot to add it to my post, sorry.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant using `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` for your whole entity. Meaning you would have to place the annotation on your class, not just the method and place all your hibernate/jpa annotation on the getters instead of the class fields. If you want to use Field access as default and only use property access in this one single case you could try adding `@Transient` to your field `private ComplexObject test`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS thx, can you post this as a answer